# isalpha replacement for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, validation

I've been trying to validate the contents of a form with JavaScript. I need to check if the 'Name' field contains only characters and whitespaces. If any other character is present, I want to display an alert. This was easy to do in C and Java but I just cant seem to find a good replacement in JavaScript. I've read about regular expressions but isn't there an easier alternative, kind of like an in-built function?

Comment: What do you mean by “only characters and whitespaces”?

Comment: Whitespaces are characters and a text input can't contain anything except characters. I think you need to rephrase.

Comment: Sorry about that, I meant alphabets :)

Comment: can you do this is javascript?

isalpha = unsigned((ch&(~(1<<5))) - 'A') <= 'Z' - 'A'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a regex is certainly easier:

```
//Check for non-alphabetic characters and space
if(name.search(/[^A-Za-z\s]/) != -1)
  alert("Invalid name");
```

Using a for loop:

```
//charCodeAt() gets the char code in a string
//Upper and lower bounds for upper case characters
var upperBoundUpper = "A".charCodeAt(0);
var lowerBoundUpper = "Z".charCodeAt(0);
//Upper and lower bounds for lower case characters
var upperBoundLower = "a".charCodeAt(0);
var lowerBoundLower = "z".charCodeAt(0);

for (var i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
  var char = name.charCodeAt(i);
  if (char <= upperBoundUpper && char >= lowerBoundUpper)
    continue;
  else if (char <= upperBoundLower && char >= lowerBoundLower)
    continue;
  //Check for space
  else if (name[i] == " ")
    continue;
  else{  //Not recognized character - not valid
    alert("Invalid name");
    break;
  }
}
```

jsPerf test for relative speed: http://jsperf.com/checking-is-alphabetic
In my tests, the for loop runs faster.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. The regex version is certainly shorter but I'm a bit more familiar with using ASCII characters for checking stuff right now. But I'll make it a point to read up on regular expressions :)

Comment: Interesting results for the speed tests. I think sometimes regexps are only used because of their black art aura, although it would be natural to assume that one line of code would execute faster than ten.

Comment: is not equivalent to isAlpha(), since it fails the Turkey test. http://www.moserware.com/2008/02/does-your-code-pass-turkey-test.html

Comment: This is marked as the correct answer, but it does not actually work. The character code for "a" is 97 and the character code for "z" is 122. This code is checking is something is less than or equal to 97 AND greater than or equal to 122, which is impossible.

Answer (score 4):

No, not that I know of.

Although you can emulate the most basic of `isalpha`'s functionality with

```
/^[ a-z]+$/i.test(string)
```

Unlike `isalpha`, this is not locale-aware, works only for the simple Latin alphabet and would be equivalent to forcing `isalpha` to run in the `C` locale.

Comment: I think that will work but I was thinking that there would be some kind of easier way (ASCII conversion and a for loop, perhaps?). I'm a noob to javascript and I've yet to learn how to convert text to their ASCII representation

Comment: I don't believe space is considered alpha.