# i want that the first two characters of my string should not be special characters

Tags: javascript

I want that the first two characters of my string should not be special characters

```
function detectInvalidChars(limitField)
{
    var len=limitField.value.length;
    var char1=limitField.value.substring(0,1);
    var char2=limitField.value.substring(1,2);

    if(char1=='&'||char1=='<' char1=='!' || char2=='&'||char2=='<'..........so on)
    {
    alert("Invalid character");
    limitField.value = limitField.value.substring(0,len-1);
    }
}
```

instead of matching the `char1` and `char2` with each special character. What can I do?

Comment: Use JavaScript RegExp! http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

Comment: What's a "special character"? Would that include, for instance, α (Greek letter alpha)? Is it easier to define the class of acceptable characters or the class of unacceptable characters?

Comment: special characters are those present in the keyboard other than numbers and albhabets. in total there are 32 special characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression:

```
var re = /^([&<!]|.[&<!])/;
if (re.test(limitField.value)) {
    alert...
}
```

Comment: What about `re.exec("a&bc")`?

Comment: @Glutamat - Oops. Revised to catch either/or instead of both. Thanks.

Comment: What about `?` character? it'll fail

Comment: @jurgemaister `\W` matches `_` which is a special character. See my answer for proper expression

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im - `\W` does not match an underscore.

Comment: @TedHopp sorry. Actually  it does not match `_` thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

look into the string method .charCodeAt(n)

you should be able to then compare the ascii values in ranges.

so for example if you want to exclude control charactercs you could write something like

```
if (mystring.charCodeAt(0)<32 || mystring.charCodeAt(1)<32) {
    alert("Invalid character");
}
```

or use a regex.

You may find this question helpful:
[isalpha replacement for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6800536/isalpha-replacement-for-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex for that on a substring of the original.

substring gets the part of the string from "from" to "to".

/^[0-9a-z]+$/ is regex that allows only 0 ... 9 and a ... z

```
function is_part_alnum(value, from, to) 
    substring = value.substring(from, to);
    if(!substring.match(/^[0-9a-z]+$/) {
        alert("Invalid character(s)");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use regex and want to define your own set of special characters, you could use a function like this:

```
function detectInvalidChars(s, count) {
    var specialChars = "!@#$%^&*()+=-[]\\\';,./{}|\":<>?~_";
    var firstChars = s.substr(0, count).split('');
    for(var i=0; i<firstChars.length; i++) {
        if(specialChars.indexOf(firstChars[i]) !== -1) {
            // invalid char detected
        }
    }
}
```

Where `s` is your string and `count` is the number of the first characters that should be investigated.